# How to use .Net IObservable::Retry with WhenAnyValue from ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, .net, exception, system.reactive, reactiveui

If I have an INPC supporting class **Numbers** with two properties **A** and **B**. I can write code like

```
Numbers numbers = new Numbers();
IObservable<double> o = numbers.WhenAnyValue(p=>p.A,p=>p.B,(a,b)=>a/b);
```

WhenAnyValue is a utility method in the ReactiveUI library for composing observables from property change events. If I then write.

```
o.Subscribe(v=>Console.WriteLine(v));
```

it will print **a/b** whenever A or B changes. This is all good until I set

```
numbers.B = 0;
```

Now **a/b** will throw a DivideByZeroException and the observable will terminate. However this is a UI. I don't want the observable to terminate. I just either wish to ignore the exception or log it and move on. First attempt is to see that IObservable contains an extension method called Retry which will reconnect to the observable after an exception. We try

```
Numbers numbers = new Numbers();
IObservable<double> o = numbers
  .WhenAnyValue(p=>p.A,p=>p.B,(a,b)=>a/b)
  .Retry();

o.Subscribe(v=>Console.WriteLine(v));
```

However when I do **numbers.B = 0** then the Retry will ignore the exception and reconnect and will immediately fail again and again and again because **WhenAnyValue** always delivers an event on subscription.

So it seems what I need is a Retry that will ignore the first input after reconnection **iff** it is the same as the input that caused the error that disconnected the first one except I don't think this is possible with RX.

Any ideas?

## Full Test Case

The below test case does not terminate.

```cs
   public class Numbers : ReactiveObject
    {
        int _A;
        public int A 
        {
            get { return _A; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _A, value); }
        }

        int _B;
        public int B 
        {
            get { return _B; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _B, value); }
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestShouldTerminate()
    {

        var numbers = new Numbers();
        var o = numbers
            .WhenAnyValue(p => p.A, p => p.B, Tuple.Create)
            .Select(v=>v.Item1/v.Item2)
            .Select(v=>v+1)
            .Retry();

        double value = 0;
        o.Subscribe(v => value = v);

        numbers.A = 10;
        numbers.B = 20;

        value.Should().Be(1.5);
    }
 }



    }



    }
```

Comment: You could add `.Where(t => t.Item2 != 0)` clause. Or you could wrap you division in Observable operation, this way `Retry` gets `OnError` and resubscribes.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be handled in vanilla RX. I've created a wrapper called

```
IObservableExceptional
IObserverExceptional
```

that changes the standard contract for error handling in RX. Errors now no longer terminate the observable. It supports LINQ and should be fairly transparent for most uses. The test case that passes is

```
    [Fact]
    public void ErrorsCanBePropogated()
    {
        var numbers = new Numbers();

        var list = new List<double>();
        var errors = new List<Exception>();

        numbers
            .WhenAnyValue(p => p.A, p => p.B, Tuple.Create)
            .ToObservableExceptional()
            .Select(v => v.Item1/v.Item2)
            .Subscribe(onNext: val=>list.Add(val), onError:err=>errors.Add(err));


        list.Count.Should().Be(0);
        errors.Count.Should().Be(1);

        numbers.A = 10;

        list.Count.Should().Be(0);
        errors.Count.Should().Be(2);

        numbers.B = 5;

        list.Count.Should().Be(1);
        list[0].Should().Be(2.0);
        errors.Count.Should().Be(2);
    }
```

The three new interfaces are

```
public interface IObservableExceptional<T>
{
    void Subscribe(IObserverExceptional<T> observer);

    IObservable<IExceptional<T>> Observable { get; }
}

public interface IObserverExceptional<T>
{
    void OnNext(IExceptional<T> t);
    void OnCompleted();
    IObserver<IExceptional<T>> Observer { get; }
}

public interface IExceptional<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    bool HasException { get; }
    Exception Exception { get; }
    T Value { get; }
    string ToMessage();
    void ThrowIfHasException();
}
```

IObservableException and IExceptional both support LINQ ( ie they are Monads )

Any exceptions thrown within the Select or SelectMany combinators of IObservableExceptional are wrapped as IExceptional objects and passed on to the subscriber. An error does not terminate the subscription.

The repository is at

https://github.com/Weingartner/Exceptional